# Does putting poor performing students on academic probation improve student performance?

Tags: motivation

As we enter a new school year, I'm wondering if the is any evidence to support or contradict the idea that putting a poor-performing students on academic probation improves their performance. Does anyone know of any such evidence?

I can imagine that schools are naturally concerned about eliminating students whose tuition keeps the doors open and my school does not have any formal rules on academic probation. I'm thinking of proposing some, but only if there is evidence that it will actually improve performance. If it demotivates students (for example creating a stigma which is a very serious issue here in Asia) and bounces students who might otherwise just pass then it does not seem so appealing.

Comment: I can imagine that the answer might be very culture-specific, so it might be worth mentioning which country you're asking about: Asia has very different cultures within it.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Confucian Asia in particular but I'm eager to hear any information about this for any part of Asia or any part of the world.

Comment: Do note that academic probation servers at least two purposes; to entice the student to perform better, as you suggest, but also to ensure that the program attracts and maintains only high-performing students.

Comment: @eykanal So weaker students are simply not welcomed? Do we normally only see academic probation at the top universities?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to academic probation due to poor grades, that's definitely part of the message. I imagine that any department with a minimum GPA requirement for their masters and PhD students—which is likely the vast majority of departments—will use academic probation when necessary.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Weaker students are simply not welcome.

Comment: @JeffE: It might be worth explaining why: weaker students can slow down the class, and drain faculty of their available time.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but universities abuse students who are not prepared for college by *not* dismissing them quickly enough.  A student who reaches the stage of academic probation should be given as much help to succeed as the university can provide, *but* a second failing term should mean dismissal, not "double-secret probation."  (I know of a university that abuses students that way.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is only a part answer

[University of California Berkeley](http://ls-probation.berkeley.edu/definition.html) applies a probation when the cumulative GPA goes below 2.0 and are within grounds for dismissal.  But, they give a semester and advise the student to:

> The College of Letters and Science encourages students who have been placed on term probation to seek advising at the Office of Undergraduate Advising for help with schedule planning and to discuss any issues that may have caused poor results in the first place. Although this web site may be helpful to you, it is primarily designed to assist probationary students whose cumulative grade point average has fallen below a 2.0.

An example from Australia, Brisbane's [Griffith University](http://www.griffith.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0010/82774/Academic_standing_flyer.pdf), it seems that a similar constraint may be applied:

> The minimum standard for academic performance is a Grade Point
>   Average (GPA) of at least 3.0 for undergraduate students and at least
>   3.5 for postgraduate students. Students who meet this GPA standard
>   are said to be in ‘good academic standing’. If a student’s GPA is below
>   this level their performance is ‘unsatisfactory’.
>   The first time a student’s performance is below the required
>   standard, the student is placed on probation for the next semester.
>   The second time a student’s performance is below the required
>   standard, the student will normally be excluded.

In the Princeton article ["The Effects of Academic Probation on College Success: Lending Students a Hand or Kicking Them While They Are Down?"](http://theop.princeton.edu/reports/wp/FletcherTokmouline_2010.pdf) (Fletcher and Tokmouline, 2010), found that often there is an improvement, but then their

> findings also suggest that this short term boost in performance fades out over time and students who are on academic probation following their first semesters of college do not have higher rates of persistence or graduation.

They also found that an overall model (indeed a definitive answer) is hard to come by due to inconsistency of heterogeneous effects, particularly

> pre-determined student characteristics as well as high school of origin.

Comment: Thanks for the link showing results of probation. This is the kind of material I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

> I'm wondering if the is any evidence to support or contradict the idea
>   that putting a poor-performing students on academic probation improves
>   their performance

Whose idea is this? I quick look at what US universities think academic probation means does not suggest that its purpose is to improve performance.

At [University of Tennessee Knoxville](http://studentsuccess.utk.edu/crisis/probation.shtml)

> Probation serves as a serious warning that your academic performance
>   needs improvement, alerting you that you are in jeopardy of Academic
>   Dismissal.

At [Harvard](http://static.fas.harvard.edu/registrar/ugrad_handbook/current/chapter5/ad_board.html) Academic Probation is defined as

> a serious warning to a student whose academic performance for the term
>   is unsatisfactory. Academic probation is a formal action of the
>   Administrative Board and becomes part of the student’s official
>   record.

It seems that in general "academic probation" is an administrative state between "good standing" and "academic dismissal". The purpose is to warn the student if they do not improve that they will be dismissed.

A potentially relevant question might be are things like the [Success Plan](http://studentsuccess.utk.edu/crisis/docs/SuccessPlan-Probation.pdf) of University of Tennessee Knoxville successful. This, however, is a really broad question. Each University is going to have a different "success plan" and implement it differently. You might also wish to consider how to build and implement a successful success plan.

Comment: The idea is that it is a serious warning which should wake up students...And is not just an administrative step, since if the students take the warning seriously, they are not dismissed.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say there is no evidence that the goal is to improve performance then you get two pieces of evidence that show students enter probation because of poor performance (implying they get out by improving their performance). Am I misreading this (note: I've not slept much recently so it is possible).

Comment: @earthling the interpretation I think is that probation is an administrative step that happens before dismissal can. So in this view it is nothing more than giving fair warning to the student that they are not performing well. This is independent of whether the department is interested in keeping that student or not. Things like probation are part of the bureaucratic tradition in the US at all levels.

Comment: @earthling my read of the guidance is that the goal is not to help students get out of probation by improving performance, but rather as a step towards dismissal. If they see it as a wake up call and improve performance, great, if not, then they are dismissed.

Comment: I think this is your personal reading @DanielE.Shub. I've always been under the impression that academic probation is a warning to encourage you to do better, not a notification that we're working on kicking you out. (Use of the royal 'we' to mean the university)

Answer (score 8):

I saw it more as "a notification that we're working on kicking you out". In my first term of college, I failed a calculus 1 class (passed 3 others, but that F pulled my gpa down to a 1.6). and was therefore placed on academic probation. My advisor then forced me to register in the second semester into 2 classes for which my failed calculus 1 class was a prereq (calculus 2 and physics), virtually ensuring that I would fail. I signed an agreement to enroll in the class, added the class, dropped it 15 minutes, and then enrolled in several easy classes in order to boost my gpa. I actually got over a 3.0 my second semester because the classes were so much easier, but I no doubt would have received F's in both the calc 2 class and the physics class had I taken them. After my second semester, I transferred out in good standing, went to the local community college for a year, and transferred to another university. Had I followed my advisor's advice, I almost certainly would have experienced academic dismissal. My take is that they were trying to get people to flunk out.

Comment: Hooray for passive-aggressive advisors.  If they wanted to kick you out, they should have just kicked you out; otherwise, it's their damn job to help you succeed.  Kudos for ignoring them.